# Freeze after usb-c dock connected Lenovo ThinkBook 13s-iml with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, freeze, 20.04, usb-c

I experience a very random behavior that I just can't find the cause for it. Whenever I plug a usb-c dock with anything plugged-in to it (doesn't matter if it's the charger, a flash drive, the monitor through hdmi or lan), the system freezes in about a minute. 
I usually boot the system up and log in to my account with the dock **unplugged**. Then I wait a bit and plug the dock in afterwards. In about a minute the UI freezes. No response to keyboard commands, mouse sometimes works but without being able to click and sometimes it doesn't move at all. 
Why I wait to log in before I plug the dock in? I noticed that every time I try to log in with the adapter plugged, it crashes the moment I click enter to log in.
Tbh I'm not sure I should rely on any "pattern" that I have observed.

I managed to get this log if it is of any help...
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I'll provide any additional information if necessary.

### Update 1:

I noticed that this doesn't happen on kernel 5.0

### Update 2:

Actually it doesn't happen specifically on Linux Mint 19.3, Kernel version 5.0.0-32-generic. When I upgraded to 5.3 the issue appeared. I tried again with Ubuntu 18 and downgrading to 5.0 but the issue was there...

### Update 3:

The issue re-occurs on Ubuntu 20.04. Based on the output I suspect it's an issue with the ucsi driver.

Comment: I have the same thing. Have you tried using Wayland? That seems to help for me. On the login screen after typing your username, click on the gear icon in the bottom right and select Wayland, then continue to type your password as usual. I've had a few solid hours without freezes with this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately that did not help...

Comment: You ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @stephan sadly, no...

Comment: I have the same problem, but it freezes instantly (using wayland, gnome, arch).